# Can I write CSS rules so that emojis get different weight than other text?

Tags: html, css, emoji

So here's my silly problem: Emoji can look bad when they are printed with high 'weight' as characters. This leads to a situation where, when you are defining your style sheet, you have to pick if you would like to make normal text look good (use bold) or if you would like emojis to look good (use normal).

Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/xjqaLypb/10/

HTML:

```html
<body>
  <div class="a">
  TEXT
  </div>
  <div class="b">
  TEXT
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
/* roboto-regular - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local(''),
       url('../fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.svg#Roboto') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

@font-face {
  font-family: emoji;
  src: local('Apple Color Emoji'),
       local('Apple Symbols'),
       local('Android Emoji'),
       local('Segoe UI'),
       local(EmojiSymbols),
       local(Symbola),
       url('font/Symbola-Emoji.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('font/Symbola-Emoji.woff') format('woff'),
       url('font/Symbola-Emoji.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 300;
  /* Emoji unicode blocks */
  unicode-range: U+1F300-1F5FF, U+1F600-1F64F, U+1F680-1F6FF, U+2600-26FF;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.a {
    font-weight: 700; /* bold */ 
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.b {
    font-weight: 400; /* normal */ 
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

The Text looks more "heading-y" when it's bolded, the emojis look more "heading-y" when they are normal.

How can I solve this? Is there a way to apply different weight rules to emojis and 'regular' text?

Edit:
The context for this is that, as you can see, mixing text and  in the same elements makes for difficult typography. I'm trying to setup a static site generator to support attractively printing s and text in the same elements.

Edit #2:
So I tried using @font-family and I have updated the jsfiddle showing the results. There seem to be two problems - the first is that I'm not sure how to specify the font weight for a fond *under a particular style.* I.e. how do I specify that, for example, Roboto should be 700 weight when "bold" and the Emoji sets should be 300 weight when "bold"?

The second, more insurmountable problem is that, even though the browser knows that it is using an  font, the document rules say to use the document font (Roboto) and so it styles the emoji font with the Roboto font-family style.
[image: Firefox inspect showing font-family Roboto with Apple Symbol font]

Comment: Maybe the answer is no - but a lot has happened since 2013 so maybe the answer has changed?

Comment: Doesn't look like it.  If you look up "css style specific character", and set the time frame to the past year, even the most recent answers all suggest js.

Answer (score -2):

Sure you can. Just do something like this:

```css
div {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.emoji {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  TEXT<span class='emoji'> This is green </span>
</div>
```

Enclose the emoji text in something like a span, add a class to the span, and you can apply whatever CSS you want to to the class.

You could also use `divs` for both your text and your emojis, and set their `display` style to `inline-block` (or learn how to use `display: flex` and `display: grid`, which give you the best control of your elements' layout), but this is simpler. It has the disadvantage that `span` doesn't recognize vertical styles like `height` and upper and lower margins, though. (For more information, see [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements).)

Using `div` tags with `display: inline-block`:

```css
    div { 
      font-weight: bold; 
    }

    .inline-div {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .emoji {
      font-weight: 400;
      color: green;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="a">
    <div class="inline-div">TEXT</div>
    <div class="inline-div emoji">This is green </div>
  </div>
```

*[Edit:]* Now that I have a better idea of what you are looking for (thanks for clarifying), you should be able to get what you are looking for with the `@font-face` "at rule." Set up your emojis as a different `@font-face` from your text. (To do this properly, each `@font-face` directive will need to reference different source files, or the lower directive will override the higher one.) Then style them any way you like. [This tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-font-face) should get you started.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm fairly certain the OP knows this, and that their question is if they can apply css rules to specific character ranges instead of the normal range, thus eliminating the need for extra markup.

Comment: @Daedalus You could be right about that, didn't occur to me. Nevertheless, I believe my post does answer the question as stated. ("Is there a way to apply different weight rules to emojis and 'regular' text?") If the OP means what you're saying, then as the dupe says, no you can't. But I wouldn't vote to close as a duplicate based on the OP's question. It doesn't state that requirement (character code references in CSS) clearly enough IMO.

Comment: Yah - the context is I'm trying to setup a static site generator and I would like to apply different styles on different font families.

Comment: @DanielDrexler In that case, have a look at `@font-face`. I've edited my post to explain further.

Comment: @BobRodes Does that tutorial(which I skimmed), enable specifying specific already-existing characters as members of the font which you define?  I ask as emoji in general are usually built in.  Such as the emoji used in this question.

Comment: @Daedalus Only in the sense of files that you specify in `src`. If the emojis are in one file and the rest of the font is in another, then you can spec them out differently. This can certainly be the case if you have emojis from one font family and the rest of your text from another. If from the same family, it's a matter of whether the font creator specifies them in separate files. As an example of one that does, you can investigate Google's Noto fonts.

Comment: @Daedalus Also, if the emojis you're using are built into the same font file as the text you're using, you could use emojis from a different font family and differentiate them from your text that way. I would think that emojis don't vary as much from one font family to another as text does.

Comment: @Daedalus If you have to use emojis and text from the same font file, one other thing you could do is set up two copies of the file, and assign different `font-family` names to each of them.